# How to route to "www.example.com/sample-article-name" to RazorPage Index.cshtmll with articleName=sample-article-name [MVC Core2.2]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How to access article by url: www.example.com/some-article-name in **Razor pages**?

I create a blog portal in `Asp.Net MVC Core 2.2` RazorPage.

I have a Page `Index.chhtml` with the method `public void OnGet(string id)`
I can access the Index with `int` parameter like that: www.example.com/234 - this work's

But putting `string`: www.example.com/some-string - doesn't work - HTTP ERROR 404

I would like access article by url: www.example.com/some-article-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of id parameter at `OnGet` method, add page parameter at the top of `index.cshtml`

```
@page "{menuUrl?}"
```

and detect its value at `OnGet` by using `RouteData.Values["menuUrl"]?.ToString()`